# How to solve this differential equation which has a square of the 1st derivative?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$Ay'' + B(y')^2 + C = 0$ where $A, B, C$ are constants.

I checked that 2nd order equations of the form $Ay'' + By' + Cy$ can be treated as $Ay^2 + By + C = 0$ and then proceeded further. But how about when the first derivative has a power term.

Any advice, or any links for a more complete solution.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You can substitute $u=y'$ to get a first order DE for $u$, solve that, and then work backwards to find $y$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Substitute $y'=z$. Let us look at the general case where the power of the first derivative is $p$.

$$Az'+Bz^p+C=0$$

Assuming $A\neq0$:
$$z'=-\frac{B}{A}z^p-\frac{C}{A}$$

This type of differential equation can be solved by separation of variables.

$$z'=-\frac{B}{A}z^2-\frac{C}{A}$$
$$\dfrac{dz}{-\frac{B}{A}z^2-\frac{C}{A}}=dx$$

If $B,C>0$

$$-\frac{A}{\sqrt{BC}}\arctan \left(\sqrt{\frac{B}{C}}z\right) =x+c$$

Comment: Can you please tell what is $w$ here?

Comment: It is the new dependent variable that you introduce. If you use that Ansatz you will get a linear ODE in $w$. Solve this then resub into $z=w^{\frac{1}{1-p}}$ and solve for z. The last step is to solve $y'=z$ by pure integration.

Comment: That differential equation for $z$ isn't Bernoulli, it's variables separable.

Comment: You are right, but it is also of Bernoulli type. I would rather think of it as a bernoulli type, for the general case, to prevent the integration of the complicated term.

Comment: Hi, when I use the substitution you suggested, I don't get a linear equation. This is because the 3rd term C/A is not having any 'z' term as a Bernoulli equation would have. Can you show a few more steps or a different approach. Thanks a lot. @MrYouMath

Comment: You are right, then you can solve it by separation of variables.